# CRC32 differs when executed on file vs text

Tags: linux, checksum, crc, crc32

I have a file called hello.txt with following content:

```
hello
```

When I execute a linux crc32 on that file like this: (I installed via sudo apt install libarchive-zip-perl)

```
crc32 hello.txt
```

I get:

```
363a3020
```

When I want to use some online calculator or npm library (crc from node.js), I execute that on text only and get the following result:

```
3610a686
```

Which is different. How could I check this so that the results are the same ? What is the difference here ? Can someone explain ?

Comment: Are you sure the input didn't change at all ?

Comment: I mean, I execute the second one on text only hello string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks as if you created the file by running something like:

```
echo hello > hello.txt
```

The echo command appends a newline character, so the content of that file is actually `hello<newline>`. We can see that with a hexdump tool, for example:

```
$ od --endian=big -x hello.txt
0000000 6865 6c6c 6f0a
0000006
```

Or by just counting bytes:

```
$ wc -c hello.txt
6 hello.txt
```

Here we see it's 6 bytes instead of the expected 5 bytes. If we suppress the terminal newline:

```
echo -n hello > hello.txt
```

We then get the expected crc:

```
$ crc32 hello.txt
3610a686
```

Comment: how can I add empty line to the buffer, when I finish file reading ? So that the last empty line will be always added ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking in your last comment, but the simple answer is just check if the last character is a `\n`, and if not, add one.